# Loop date in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to get the sum of each day and make additional stuff to sub query, unfortunately I've tried lots of ideas and really can't figure it out how to do it.

This is what i have so far and it's taking the sum of the first day. This is what i did to check that at least first day works.

```
    SELECT
     INVOICE_DATE
    ,INVOICE_COUNT as "Number of Invoices"
    ,<here> as "Team percentage"
FROM 
    <table_name>
WHERE 
    user = :P2_USER 
AND 
    invoice_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P2_FROM, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:P2_TO, 'MM/DD/YYYY') ORDER BY created_date
```

The formula goes :

= (sum(INVOICE_COUNT) of the :P2_USER on specific day * 100) / (sum(INVOICE_COUNT)of all users on specific day)

All details are in the same table

Comment: Where dose "ERROR_COUNT" come from?

Comment: Error count keeps the errors i have in my program . I left it there to show that i will need multiple values in my query and i can’t use only one .

Comment: I have updated @samabcde

Comment: It is unclear what data you want from your SQL (which you stated does not work as you expected). Please describe what results you want with text instead of with non-working SQL.

Comment: @KCWong , I have updated with more details.

Comment: @AdrianNicolae In that case, samabcde's answer will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following sql, to do such query you need to join the result set for all team member and individual team member using "input_date"

```
SELECT individual_count.in_date,
  TO_CHAR( individual_count.sum_in_count * 100 / all_count.sum_in_count , '99.99') AS "Team percentage"
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(IN_COUNT) AS sum_in_count,
    in_date
  FROM <in_table>
  WHERE in_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P2_FROM, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:P2_TO, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND username = :P2_USER
  GROUP BY in_date
  ) AS individual_count
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(IN_COUNT) AS sum_in_count,
    in_date
  FROM <in_table>
  WHERE in_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P2_FROM, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:P2_TO, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  GROUP BY in_date
  ) AS all_count
ON individual_count.in_date = all_count.in_date;
```

Comment: Got a ORA-00936: missing expression but I try to fix it. Thank you ! I will tell you shortly .

Comment: The column name is missing in the two "WHERE BETWEEN" clauses. Change it to "WHERE in_date BETWEEN" will work.

Comment: Also, you can remove "AS" from the two sub-tables, i.e. ") AS individual_count" to ") individual_count".